# How do I check if a string is composed only of letters and numbers? (PHP)

Tags: php

Title says it all: I am checking to see if a user's username contains anything that isn't a number or letter, such as €{¥]^}+<€, punctuation, spaces or even things like âæłęč. Is this possible in php?

Comment: You can do this, but why? Mr James O'Reilly, Ms Victoria Van de Waal, and Monsieur René Duchamps might all have something to say about it.

Comment: @Redd Herring I want to store the username as something that doesn't have special characters so you can't have things like invisible names with invisible characters and stuff. Basically I wanna just type 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ and check if every character is part of that list.

Comment: Fair enough. I misread your question and interpreted username to mean user's name. Apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`ctype_alnum()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) function in PHP.

From the manual..

> Check for alphanumeric character(s)
>   Returns TRUE if every character in text is either a letter or a digit, FALSE otherwise.

```php
var_dump(ctype_alnum("æøsads")); // false
var_dump(ctype_alnum("123asd")); // true
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/5etr7

Comment: To it be safe for use, the variable must be a string. If the input provided is an integer, eg. 13, it will return false. I whould wrap the value on `strval()` to avoid this situation, unless the OP have sure that the value will always be string even with numeric values.

Comment: "Note:

If an integer between -128 and 255 inclusive is provided, it is interpreted as the ASCII value of a single character (negative values have 256 added in order to allow characters in the Extended ASCII range). Any other integer is interpreted as a string containing the decimal digits of the integer."

Comment: @Qirel That looks like what im looking for! Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

## PHP does REGEX

What you want to do is fairly trivial, [PHP has a number of regex functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php)

### Testing a String For a Character

If all you want is to know **IF** a string contains non-alphanumeric characters, then just use **preg_match()**:

```
preg_match( '/[^A-Za-z0-9]*/', $userName );
```

This will **return 1** if the username contains anything *other than* alphanumeric (A-Z or a-z or 0to9), it **returns 0** if it *doesn't* contain a non-alphanumeric.

### Regex Pattern Elements

Regex PCRE patterns open and close with a delimiter such as a slash`/`, and that needs to be treated like a string (quoted):`'/myPattern/'` Some other key features are:

**[ brackets contain match sets ]**
`[a-z]  // means match any lowercase letter`
This pattern means check the current character in the $String relative to the pattern in these brackets, in this case match any lowercase letter a to z.

**^ Caret** (Meta-Character)
`[^a-z]  // means no lowercase letters` If the caret ^ (aka hat) is the first character *inside brackets*, it NEGATES the pattern inside brackets so `[^A7]` means match anything *EXCEPT* uppercase A and the numeral 7. (*Note: when **outside** brackets, the caret ^ means the start of the string*.)

**\w\W\d\D\s\S. Meta-Characters** (WildCards)
`\w  // match all alphanumeric` An escaped (i.e. preceded by a backslash \ ) lowercase w means match any "word" character, i.e. alphanumeric and the underscore _, this is shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. The uppercase `\W` is the *NOT* word character, equivalent to `[^A-Za-z0-9_] or [^\w]`

```
.   // (dot) match ANY single character except return/newline
\w  // match any word character [A-Za-z0-9_]
\W  // NOT any word character [^A-Za-z0-9_]
\d  // match any digit [0-9]
\D  // NOT any digit [^0-9].
\s  // match any whitespace (tab, space, newline)
\S  // NOT any whitespace
```

**.*+?| Meta-Characters** (Quantifiers))
These modify the behavior outside of a set []

```
*   // match previous character or [set] zero or more times, 
    // so .* means match everything (including nothing) until reaching a return/newline.
+   // match previous at least one or more times.
?   // match previous only zero or one time (i.e. optional).
|   // means logical OR eg.: com|net means match either literal "com" or "net"
```

**Not shown:** capture groups, backreferences, substitution (the real power of regex). See https://www.phpliveregex.com/#tab-preg-match for more including a live pattern-match playground that is based on the PHP functions, and delivers results as arrays.

### Back To Your StringCleaning

So for your pattern, to match all non-letters and numbers (including underscores) you need either: `'/[^A-Za-z0-9]*/'  or  '/[\W_]*/'`

#### Strip Search

If instead you want to STRIP all the non-alpha characters from a string then use `preg_replace( $Regex, $Replacement, $StringToClean )`

```
<?php
    $username = 'Svéñ déGööfinøff';
    echo preg_replace('/[\W_]*/', '', $username);
?>
```

The output is: **`SvdGfinff`** If you'd prefer to replace *certain* accented letters with standard latin ones to keep the names reasonably readable, then I believe you'd need a lookup table (array). [There is one ready to use at the PHP site](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#96586)